# RPI - Nikon 1J5 - Wifi Trigger (help)

Tags: wifi, camera

I've setup a timelapse stepper motor slider with the RPI. Upon boot it starts the slider with a specific step & delay. Goes back and forth until the RPI is powered off.

I have a Nikon 1J5, for remote trigger since it only has USB & HDMI, there is an app called Nikon wireless mobile utility. What I want to do is have the RPI connect to the nikons wifi, and remote trigger the camera every time the slider moves (So its in sync and doesn't cause any motion blur for long exposures)
However, to do so I haven't got the slightest clue what the nikon app API uses to talk to the camera.

I've looked everywhere but am unsure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: I don't really agree that this question is off-topic, but in case it gets closed down, I suggest @Casper to ask on https://photo.stackexchange.com/